# showing comment on the same page using jquery_ujs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm developing a commenting feature in my Rails app. I want to show the comment to the user immediately after he clicks a post button.
i have a form for creating the button and i want to show the comment using JQuery_ujs. what is the best way to do it?

this is the create comment action:

```
def create_comment
  params.permit!
  @article = Article.find(params[:article][:id])
   @comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])
   @comment.article_id = @article.id

     if @comment.save
        render :text => 'created', :status => 202 and return
     else
        render :text => "not created", :status => 203 and return
     end
end
```

this is the jquery script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function (e) {


    e.preventDefault();

    var commentor =this.comment_commentor.val();
    var comment =this.comment_content.val();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: '<%=create_comment_comment_index_path%>',
        // send the last id to our rails app
        data: {
            commentor: commentor,
            comment: content,
        },

        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        if(jqXHR.status == "203"){
          //invalid
        }else if(jqXHR.status == "202"){
          //valid

          $('#comments').append("<div class='well'>
   <p class='text-muted'>Added by <strong><%=@acomment.commentor%></strong> on <%= l(@comment.created_at, format: '%B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S') %>
     </p>
   <blockquote>
    <p><%=comm.content%></p>
   </blockquote>
       </div>");
        }
      }
    });

});
 });
```

this is how i show the comments:

```
<div id="comments">
<%@article.comments.each do |comm|%>
<div class="well">
<p class="text-muted">Added by <strong><%=comm.commentor%></strong> on
<%= l(comm.created_at, format: '%B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S') %></p>
<blockquote>
<p><%=comm.content%></p>
</blockquote>
</div>
<%end%>
</div>
```

the form for creating comments:

```
<%= form_for(:comment, :url => create_comment_comment_index_path) do |f| %>
  <input type="hidden" value="<%=params[:id]%>" name="article[id]">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :commentor,:class=>"form-control", :required=>"true"%>
    </div>
  <br>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.text_area :content,:class=>"form-control", :required=>"true"%>
 </div>
<br>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "create",:id=>"submit",:class=>"btn btn-lg btn-primary "%>
</div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML

Comment: edited my question, i'am not sure if the code is okay i haven't tested yet.

Comment: Your approach is correct . The best way is using an Ajax then in success call back function you can pass your data that server returns back . There are two options here either you generate your new comment HTML in server-side and return it as a text and then append the data to your element or do what you are doing now.You can use Browser's console to debug your Javascript.

Comment: Okay but there is a problem that after submitting the comment a new page is rendered and the text " created " is displayed only on a new page, i want the user to stay on the same page after submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another user commented, you do have 2 choices, make your updates in a callback, or make your updates in UJS.  Personally I find it easier to respond with JSON when you're using the callback method, but that's just personal preference.

If you choose to go with UJS you don't have to change much.

- call to create as you're doing now
- using `remote: true` to force a javascript request
- change your current view comment list item to render from a partial
- make sure your controller can respond to js
- then add your ujs file, e.g. `create.js.erb`
- delete your jquery script

The comments section would look more like:

```
<div id="comments">
    <%@article.comments.each do |comm|%>
      <%= render comm %>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

Then your `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` would be something like:

```
<div class="well">
    <p class="text-muted">Added by <strong><%=commment.commentor%></strong> on
    <%= l(comment.created_at, format: '%B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S') %></p>
    <blockquote>
        <p><%=commment.content%></p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

This way your UJS file can look like:

```
$('#comments').prepend('<%= j render("comment", comment: @comment) >');
$('form#new_comment').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
```

This will add the newly created comment at the top of the list of comments.

See sample app: https://github.com/trh/rails_ujs_comments_example_app

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you.